# Best practice to schedule a long running django batch job on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, batch-processing

I have developed a Django web application that runs in Heroku. Everything has been working fine using 1 web dyno. Now I need to run a web scraping batch job (also in Django) that takes approximately 12 hours to complete. I plan to execute it twice a week.  Which would be the best way to accomplish this? Heroku documentation recommends using worker dynos and a scheduler to initiate the request. As far as I know, If I implement it this way I will have to pay for an entire worker dyno even if it is used only 24 hours a week. The other option is to execute the batch job within the scheduler but Heroku does not recommend executing long lasting processes that way. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: kindly add the code that you have tried.

Comment: I can't imagine what kind of web scraping job would take 12 hours(!) - but regardless, even if it's only a minute or so, you need that worker dyno. I have had to do something similar. If you don't like the price, and can't move to free dynos (which you shouldn't be using for a production application), then perhaps Heroku isn't the right platform for your application.

Comment: The code is just a Beautifulsoup script that scrapes several e-commerce sites with thousands of products. That’s why it takes so long to finish. For now it is just a personal project and I am using a Hobby dyno for the web application. Do you know if it possible to use a free dyno for that worker process? Thanks!